# How to make module run on Sheet1 when Cell in Sheet 2 Changes?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module called "pulldata" that pulls data from the web.

I would like it to run on Sheet1 and show data on B2 when cell F1 in Sheet2 changes in value. I have tried tried using worksheet change and worksheet calculate on Sheet1 but it still does not run. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub pulldata()
'
' pulldata Macro
'
'
sTicker = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
If sTicker = "" Then
MsgBox "No value to look up"
Exit Sub
End If
With Worksheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" _
, Destination:=Range("B2"))
.Name = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = False
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
.WebTables = "6"
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to watch for a change in "Sheet2", you need to have a `Worksheet_Change` event in "Sheet2", e.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1.pulldata
    End If
End Sub
```

---

I would recommend, however, that you move your `pulldata` routine into a standard code module.  Before you do though, you should change `Destination:=Range("B2")` to be `Destination:=Worksheets(1).Range("B2")` to ensure that the range is fully qualified so that it refers to sheet1.

Comment: Will do. Can you offer the full worksheet_change code I should use for Sheet2?

Comment: The full code for the `Worksheet_Change` is in the answer.  It checks whether F1 has changed and, if so, invokes the `pulldata` macro (currently in the `Sheet1` module).

Comment: OMG it works. I have been trying to figure it out for days! Thank you.